# Unable to return output of PHP function, while echo displays string

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I am using a PHP function to output a string of HTML. I was initially just echoing the output, but my HTML was displaying too high on the page when I did that. In the past, using ob_start() and returning ob_get_clean() has solved this issue, yet it is not working in this case. In fact, when I use this method, no HTML is output at all. When I use var_dump() on the variable, it is confirming that my HTML string is indeed being saved into the object, yet return still outputs nothing.

```
<?php

add_shortcode( 'slider-display', 'slider_display' );

function slider_display(){


$slider_html = '';
ob_start();
?>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container one-column-swiper" id="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class='slide-content'>
                <img src="img.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class='slide-content'>
                <img src="img.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
$slider_html = ob_get_clean();
return $slider_html;


} //end function
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you echoing the output of `slider_display()`? ie. `echo slider_display()`? Where are you calling this function from?

Comment: I agree, the problem is most likely with the way you're using the function. The function itself looks fine.

Comment: I am calling the function from a shortcode in wordpress. I have edited the post for context.

Comment: Are you sure the shortcode allows PHP code execution? If they allow HTML they dont have to allow PHP too (unless you specifically told wordpress to ofcourse!)

Comment: Is the entire page blank, or only the section where the slider should be?

Comment: Were you using it the same way before you changed it to return a string? I don't use WP, but apparently it expects the function to echo the output itself, not return a string.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure that I can execute PHP from a shortcode, it has worked in the past. Only the section where the slider should be is blank.

If there is nothing apparently wrong with the way I constricted this function, maybe there is another way to print a variable other than echo or return? Thank you all

Comment: tested your code, works on clean installation... @Barma a shortcode should end every time with a return. CandyPaintedRIMS any Caching Plugins activ?